# How to reduce CPU usage in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory, cpu-usage

I am checking CPU usage in my project, it will display 40%-70% in idle mode.

I want reduce CPU usage in my application.

I found some code in internet, but not reduce CPU usage.

```
code :

Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true; 
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

How can i do that?

If anyone know the ans tell me some idea to do this.

thanks.

Comment: Not running this code will improve cpu usage

Comment: how to reduce CPU usage in wp7.. now cup usage is 45-70 i want to reduce 30-40 like that. if you know any idea tell me

Comment: First, find the code that is keeping the CPU busy. Then, optimize the code. After that, if you don't succeed, post the code and ask us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has an article on just this subject:

[How to: Identify and Fix Common Performance Issues Using Windows Phone Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202932%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)